# Replacing multiple values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, replace

I have some JSON which I'd like to change the values in:

```
[
  {
    "Roster Reports": "Work Roster"
  },
  {
    "#untitled--19": "Start Date:",
    "#untitled--26": "01/11/2021",
    "#untitled--34": "End Date:",
    "#untitled--43": "28/11/2021"
  },
  {
    "#untitled": "Nov 2021",
    "#untitled--5": "Mon",
    "#untitled--7": "Tue",
    "#untitled--9": "Wed",
    "#untitled--11": "Thu",
    "#untitled--13": "Fri",
    "#untitled--15": "Sat",
    "#untitled--17": "Sun",
    "#untitled--20": "Mon",
    "#untitled--22": "Tue",
    "#untitled--24": "Wed",
    "#untitled--28": "Thu",
    "#untitled--31": "Fri",
    "#untitled--36": "Sat",
    "#untitled--39": "Sun",
    "#untitled--41": "Mon",
    "#untitled--45": "Tue",
    "#untitled--48": "Wed",
    "#untitled--50": "Thu",
    "#untitled--52": "Fri",
    "#untitled--54": "Sat",
    "#untitled--56": "Sun",
    "#untitled--58": "Mon",
    "#untitled--60": "Tue",
    "#untitled--62": "Wed",
    "#untitled--64": "Thu",
    "#untitled--66": "Fri",
    "#untitled--68": "Sat",
    "#untitled--70": "Sun"
  },
  {
    "#untitled--5": 1,
    "#untitled--7": 2,
    "#untitled--9": 3,
    "#untitled--11": 4,
    "#untitled--13": 5,
    "#untitled--15": 6,
    "#untitled--17": 7,
    "#untitled--20": 8,
    "#untitled--22": 9,
    "#untitled--24": 10,
    "#untitled--28": 11,
    "#untitled--31": 12,
    "#untitled--36": 13,
    "#untitled--39": 14,
    "#untitled--41": 15,
    "#untitled--45": 16,
    "#untitled--48": 17,
    "#untitled--50": 18,
    "#untitled--52": 19,
    "#untitled--54": 20,
    "#untitled--56": 21,
    "#untitled--58": 22,
    "#untitled--60": 23,
    "#untitled--62": 24,
    "#untitled--64": 25,
    "#untitled--66": 26,
    "#untitled--68": 27,
    "#untitled--70": 28
  },   
{
    "#untitled--5": "LD:GMTA",
    "#untitled--7": "D4~:GMTA",
    "#untitled--9": "D4~:GMTA",
    "#untitled--11": "D3:GMTA",
    "#untitled--13": "A/C:GMTA",
    "#untitled--20": "A/C:GMTA",
    "#untitled--24": "D5:GMTA",
    "#untitled--28": "A/C:GMTA",
    "#untitled--31": "A/C:GMTA",
    "#untitled--41": "LD:GMTA",
    "#untitled--50": "D4:GMTA",
    "#untitled--52": "A/C:GMTA",
    "#untitled--54": "LD:GMTA",
    "#untitled--60": "D5:GMTA",
    "#untitled--64": "N:GMTA",
    "#untitled--66": "N:GMTA",
    "#untitled--68": "N:GMTA",
    "#untitled--70": "N:GMTA"
  },
  {
    "#untitled--11": "08:00 - 18:00",
    "#untitled--20": "08:00 - 19:00"
  },
  {
    "#untitled--20": "AC1:GMTA",
    "#untitled--60": "AC1:GMTA"
  },
  {
    "#untitled": "Sauce"
  },
  {
    "#untitled": "Rosy",
    "#untitled--7": "D4:GMTA",
    "#untitled--11": "E4:GMTA",
    "#untitled--15": "D3♥:GMTA",
    "#untitled--22": "LD:GMTA",
    "#untitled--28": "D4:GMTA",
    "#untitled--45": "A/L",
    "#untitled--48": "A/L",
    "#untitled--50": "A/L",
    "#untitled--52": "A/L",
    "#untitled--60": "LD:GMTA",
    "#untitled--64": "A/L"
  }
]
```

I'd like to change all the values held in the

```
{
    "#untitled--5": 1,
    "#untitled--7": 2,
    "#untitled--9": 3,
    "#untitled--11": 4,
    "#untitled--13": 5,
    "#untitled--15": 6,
    "#untitled--17": 7,
    "#untitled--20": 8 .... }
```

part of the code (x[3]) so that all instances of "#untitled--5" in the JSON are replaced with the corresponding value (in this case, 1), and all instances of "#untitled--7" are replaced with 2, and so on. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut, but you can map over the values and deal with it:

```js
// assume your json is called `json`
// Step 1: parse it.
let x = JSON.parse(json);
// Map over the objects are override the values of the keys
x = x.map(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (x[3][key] && obj[key]) {
      obj[key] = x[3][key]
    }
  });
});
// Stringify back into JSON.
const finalJSON = JSON.stringify(x);
```